# Twistd executable on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, twisted

I have a Twisted daemon application that works without raising any problem on Python 2 using twistd. However, I want to support Python3 as well, and although all my code works, it seems that the twistd executable is not present on the Twisted version for python 3 (apparently the `twisted.scripts` package is not included). Has anybody found a workaround for this? Sure I can run my daemons without twistd, but it would make the task a bit more complicated and I think it is a elegant way as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only some parts of Twisted are currently ported to Python 3 and I think the `twisted.scripts` package is not yet available.

You can find [here](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/Plan/Python3) status of this ongoing work, and the [Porting to Python 3](http://twisted.readthedocs.org/en/latest/core/howto/python3.html) documentation page links to the [twisted.python.dist3](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/browser/trunk/twisted/python/dist3.py) module which describes the currently ported modules.

Comment: Thanks! I already had a look at those, and sadly it is not supported yet :/ . I decided to do a separate init script for Python 3 that does all the twistd tasks, then I install the appropriate one for the python version in the system...

Comment: The “workaround” for this is to become active in the Twisted community and contribute patches which migrate the `twisted.scripts` package so that it can be installed in Python.  Just waiting around for someone to port the pieces you want will probably work *eventually*, but it won't be on the timeline you care about :).